# How to load the parent page again on the close of child pop up page in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, reload

I am trying to do the following:

- I have a parent page "movies", in which I have a button "add movies". which when clicked would open a pop-up page.
- I will add the new movie and click on save in pop-up page. It will be added to the database as expected.
- However, after adding the new movie, pop will close and control comes to the parent page and it should display the newly added movie name there, which is not happening.
- The parent page will show the newly added movie name if I refresh the page. I want the parent page to show the newly added movie when the pop-up closes itself.

Comment: No need to refresh... Once you got the success close the popup then parent page is there so call the api service update your latest content. If you've local data then add it into your existing list

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... I'm using the modal controller for the pop-up... After closing the child page I'm again making a call to the API from the parent page, However, it's still not showing the newly added movie on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the `MatDialogModule`.
In that case, you can parse the result to the parent component on the dialogues `afterClosed()` and add the new movie to the list.

See this example here : https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples#dialog-overview

Or:

```js
class ParentComponent {
 constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

 addMovie(){
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open()
  
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(newMovie => <add new movie to list of movies>)
 }
}
```

```js
class MovieDialog {
 constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>)

 submitMovie() {
  this.dialogRef.close(newMovie)
 }

}
```

So In the `ParentComponent` we listen on `afterClosed()` which will get the newMovie when the `MovieDialog` `this.dialogRef.close(newMovie)` closes the dialog and emits the new movie.

EDIT:
Based on your comment, you might be experiencing Angular not detecting a change to the array containing the movies:

```js
public movies = ['star wars', Harry Potter'] // your array before adding a movie

// if you the add a movie to the array eg. 
this.movies.push('Top Gun');

// then it might look like this: ['star wars', Harry Potter', 'Top Gun']
// But Angular hasn´t detected the change because the array itself didn´t change. 

// after the array.push, try to override the array again: 
this.movies.push('Top Gun');
this.movies = [...this.movies] // <- the spread opertaor is very important for this to work
```

Also, remember to inspect the network call to ensure that the backed actually returns the list with the new movie

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... I'm using the modal controller for the pop-up... After closing the child page I'm again making a call to the API from the parent page, However, it's still not showing the newly added movie on the parent page.

Comment: please se my updated answer